# Installing modules in windows not in Anaconda

Tags: python, conda

I installed anaconda and installed various modules in it. Later I uninstalled it but when I try to install packages in Python through command line, it says requirements already satisfied and doesn't install. I want to install modules in simple Python now not in anaconda. How to fix it? Also, if I have uninstalled anaconda, why do I get the requirements satisfied message?

Comment: How are you trying to install the packages? Can you share the actual input and output?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear what you are trying to achieve , but you can always install the packages in a new location , and point the Python script to the new locations.

Python -m pip install --target="New location" [package name]